# SQL long format to wide format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table with the format

```
order_id    order_items
6161        ["7040","1308","1308"]
7234        ["22"]
```

I would need to convert the format to the below

```
order _id  I_7040   I_1308   I_22
6162       true     true     false
7234       false     false    true
```

Comment: what database is this for? (MySQL? Oracle?...) "sql" by itself is not sufficient. You data model needs fixing and you are also going to be dealing with `dynamic sql` to achieve those column headings.

Comment: and be precise with your example - you have order id 6161 and then 6162

Comment: what is the data type for order_items?

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your reply.. order id can be anything and its not in sequence.. and for data type for order_items is integer..

Comment: I know you are a newbie from exp points, but what you have is a very POOR structure.  You should have a separate detail table for each individual row per order id.

Comment: It can't be an integer - you are expressing it as a list of strings. Please post the actual data structure - the `create table` statement

Comment: @Alan : my bad ..its varchar..sorry for that

Comment: Can the structure be changed or are you stuck with this (awful) one? How many order item ids are you having to track (you show three, one repeated)? how many records in total are there? What's the total number of order_items possible for any one order_id?

Comment: struck with same format:(

Comment: That's not just a poor design, that's a horrible design

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use such like `regexp_substr(t.order_items,'7040')='7040'` collations with `case..when` expressions :

```
select t.order_id,
       ( case when regexp_substr(t.order_items,'7040')='7040' then
          'true'
         else
          'false'
         end ) as "I_7040",
       ( case when regexp_substr(t.order_items,'1308')='1308' then
          'true'
         else
          'false'
         end ) as "I_1308",   
       ( case when regexp_substr(t.order_items,'22')='22' then
          'true'
         else
          'false'
         end ) as "I_22"
  from tab t;
```

[***`SQL Fiddle Demo`***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c29af1/1)